High Throughput Interface between different FPGA vendors
Is there an industry standard Chip to Chip communication protocol that defines both the PMA and PCS layers ?
For example, Interlaken is used for Chip to Chip communication - but from what I've read it's PHY agnostic - so probably different FPGA families from different vendors will have different transceiver technologies making the PHY's incompatible.
To be clear, I'm looking for data rates in the range of >25Gbits/s across a limited number of lanes (so source synchronous LVDS isn't an option).

There are a number of different device to device comms protocols.
PCIe springs to mind immediately. Many higher end FPGAs have PCIe hardened IP within them, typically capable of being both a root complex and an endpoint. This is a very well defined standard. A Gen 3x4 PCIe link could easily give you 25Gpbs throughput.
Ethernet has a chip to chip variant. Though 25Gbps would be tough, you could use a 40G or 100G Ethernet link.
There are also lots of other protocols that could be used. Interlaken is royalty free, well supported and scalable to high bandwidths (6Gbps per lane). JESD204 which is used for data converters typically can be used for any data really, and is again supported by many FPGA vendors.
These all use high speed transceivers, which lots of FPGAs have built in. The transceivers are typically CML signalling. On the contrary to your remarks about incompatibility, this is not really the case. Because things like PCIe are well defined standards, the transceivers from different FPGAs and vendors will be interoperable (CML is usually AC coupled to cope with different DC bias levels).

PCIe is an option, but as you mentioned, one of the FPGA's would have to be the root complex and also (correct me if I'm wrong here), the TLP layer will have to be implemented on both devices. I'm looking for a simple point to point option.

@shaiko Intel have some examples designs for PCIe. I'd say though that Interlaken like you already find would probably be simpler - it should use essentially the same transceivers in the FPGA as PCIe does, so should be interoperable between different t vendors devices.

Have you come across examples of 2 FPGAs communicating via PCIe without software orchestrating the data transfers between the devices ?

While Aurora was created by Xilinx (now AMD) there are specifications available:

Aurora 8B/10B Protocol Specification
Aurora 64B/66B Protocol Specification

Both the above specification describe physical coding sublayer (PCS) and physical medium attachment (PMA) layer functions.
I found A.L.S.E have IP to support Aurora on FPGA or ASIC devices from other manufacturers:

Aurora 8B/10B IP Core
Aurora 64B/66B IP Core

I haven't used the A.L.S.E Aurora IP myself but the above web pages do indicate the non-Xilinx supported devices:

Our IP makes Aurora 8B/10B available to other FPGAs (and potentially ASICs), including Intel-FPGAs, but also Lattice (Certus Pro NX) and Microchip (PolarFire).
Therefore, IP provides an efficient way to interconnect a Xilinx FPGA (for example) with an Intel or Lattice or Microchip FPGA, or any other chip (ASIC, ASSP, etc …) using the Aurora 8B/10B public protocol.


The ALSE Aurora 64B/66B IP core is a very compact and optimized implementation of this protocol, also developed and verified to ensure full compatibility with the Xilinx IP core (interoperability has been tested and demonstrated).
This IP is available on all the high-end Intel FPGAs (from Stratix V and Cyclone10gx to Agilex-7 and Agilex-5) but is now available for other vendors including Lattice and Microchip PolarFire. Last but not least, we have developed and delivered an ASIC version of our IP !

